# Using vuex inside a manually-mounted vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I'm manually mounting a component to a dynamic element using `Vue.extend` like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import MyComponent from 'MyComponent.vue';

const MyComponentConstructor = Vue.extend(MyComponent);
const MyComponent = new MyComponentConstructor({
    propsData: {
        foo: 123,
    },
}).$mount('#mount-point');
```

When I manually mount a component in this way, I can't use `vuex` inside `MyComponent.vue`.:

```
// (inside MyComponent.vue)
this.$store.commit('setSomething', true);
```

I get this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined

Of course `vuex` is set up and working fine in the other normal components. Is there something I can pass to the constructor to get it to work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pass the store as part of the options to the constructor.

```
import store from "path/to/store"

const MyComponent = new MyComponentConstructor({
    store,
    propsData: {
        foo: 123,
    },
}).$mount('#mount-point');
```

Comment: Wow, simple as that! Thanks! 
It looks like I can also pass `store: this.$store` from the parent component so I don't even have to import the store!

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little late to the party, still felt the urge to chime this in.
The best approach I've found is to pass the `parent` key as the actual parent if you have access to it (it'll be `this` on the mounting parent usually). So you'll do:

```
const MyComponent = new MyComponentConstructor({
    parent: this,
    propsData: {
        foo: 123,
    },
}).$mount('#mount-point')
```

You'll have access to other useful globals (like `$route`, `$router`, and of course `$store`) within the mounted component instance. This also properly informs `Vue` of the component hierarchy making `MyComponent` visible in the dev-tools.

Comment: This is a better approach because, in most case, we just want to create a new child component rather than a new App. By using `parent` prop, the new component will extends all features we added to App.